# Excel row in cell

Tags: c#, excel, row, cell, excel-interop

Is there a possibility to access on a row of a cell with 2 or more rows in it? For e.g. look below:

[image]
The rows are in ONE Cell!

Comment: Split the contents of the Cell on LineBreaks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
When acessing on a cell with multiple rows, the rows are seperated by "\n".
I just replaced them with string.replace(....), and accessed on them with substrings.
Thank you!